# Add a property to a relation from a csvfile in Neo4j when there is no direct relation between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have these 3 nodes (User,Tweet,Token) like:

```
:User with this property {userID}
:Token with this property {word}
:Tweet with this properties {tweetID, userID, tweetTxt}
```

and currently the relations are as follow:

`(:Tweet)<-[:MADE]-(:User)
(:Token)<-[:CONTAINS {tweet_score}]-(:Tweet)`

Now consider the following csv file:

```
userToken.csv
_________________________________________
token,userID,score
that_danielle,15990804,0.111140564157
foodies,15990804,0.159946268074
soft-launched,15990804,0.132826927255
email,60730027,0.0561669544423
email,60730027,0.105124263028
email,60730027,0.0453705868273
email,60730027,0.0967876752689
email,32785000,0.101566813224
you,60730027,0.0835723672219
```

I need to add a new property called "user_score" to the "CONTAINS" relation and this score should be retrieved from userToken.csv file. In the following code I tried to do like this: match "p" to contain all the :Token nodes that a user have (not sure if that really works!), then with these "p"s add the "user_score" from csv file to "CONTAINS" relation:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///..../userToken.csv" AS csvrow
MATCH p=(u:User)-[*2]->(tok:Token)
with p
where u.userID = toInt(csvrow.userID)
FOREACH (n IN nodes(p)| SET n.user_score = toFloat(csvrow.score) )
```

[image: Here is how my nodes and relations look like!!!]

This returns an error:

```
"csvrow not defined (line 6, column 52 (offset: 258))
"FOREACH (n IN nodes(p)| SET n.user_score = toFloat(csvrow.score) )""
```

Can you please help me to fix it?

P.S: not sure about the title of my question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///..../userToken.csv" AS csvrow
MATCH p=(u:User)-[*2]->(tok:Token)
with p
where u.userID = toInt(csvrow.userID)
FOREACH (n IN nodes(p)| SET n.user_score = toFloat(csvrow.score) )
```

Everything that is not passed in the `WITH` is not available after it, so as you don't pass `csvrow` it is no more bound to the remaining part of the query.

However, you absolutely don't need a with here. Secondly, your query here will add the score to all nodes in the path, so on the User node, the tweet and the token.

As you want to put it on the `CONTAINS` relationship, you can do it like this :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///..../userToken.csv" AS csvrow
MATCH (u:User)
where u.userID = toInt(csvrow.userID)
MATCH (u)-[:MADE]->(tweet)-[r:CONTAINS]->(token)
SET r.user_score = csvrow.score
```

This query however will add a the user_score also to the user node

Edit after comment (assuming the property key on the token node is `name`:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///..../userToken.csv" AS csvrow
MATCH (u:User)
where u.userID = toInt(csvrow.userID)
MATCH (u)-[:MADE]->(tweet)-[r:CONTAINS]->(token)
WHERE token.name = csvrow.token
SET r.user_score = csvrow.score
```

Comment: Thanks Christophe, Good point forusing `WITH`. However, none of the queries gave me the correct result. It can't find the correct :Token matching with the :User. The scenario is like the :User makes a `:Tweet` and this `:Tweet` is a bunch of words stored in :Token (they have the :CONTAINS relation). Now I wanna add the `user_score` from the userToken.csv, this means I'm weighting each `:Token` for each `:User` that used a `:Token` in the related `:Tweet`. These queries can't match the `:User` and `:Token` correctly. If I just could have `tweetId` in the CSV file it would be a super easy thing

Comment: It worked!! The last query dose what I need. And your assumption for having a key on `name` was correct. Thanks Christophe!

Comment: Great ! Glad it helped